# javascript performance functionality

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, firefox, google-chrome

I'm not sure if such tool exists but if it does, please point me to it.

It works like this: you play with the UI of you page for a few minutes and then you can see how many times the browser spent executing each javascript function and how much time does each function take to execute on average.

So for instance, we could say function X is used a lot and takes a long time to execute.

I use chrome so may be other browsers do this. Let me know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

chrome's developer tools has what you call "Timeline".

1. load your page then CTRL + SHIFT + I
2. go to Timeline tab
3. hit the record button (found on the lower left, it's a circle).

then it will record your actions, page events, etc.

Comment: yes, I know about timeline but it doesn't display information for my javascript functions, just for browser events like reflows and licks.

Comment: Have you tried the Profiles tab in Chrome's developer tools?  It has a similar interface to the Timeline: you press record, then start doing things with the UI, and then stop recording.  The profile then shows the functions that were used, alongside % of time taken.

Comment: ah, profiles is pretty cool; is there a way to only show a certain script? I'm using jquery a lot and function calls to my functions don't show very well.

Comment: you need to do a combination of both.

Comment: @frenchie You can select a function and choose to either exclude it (× button at the bottom) or focus on it exclusively (eyeball button).

Answer (score 1):

1) JSLitmus is a lightweight tool for creating ad-hoc JavaScript benchmark tests

http://www.broofa.com/Tools/JSLitmus/

is best and calculates for all browsers

2) Firebug, Chrome will also help.

3) JSPerf (dont have the link) will also help you check performance online

4)

and if you are not happy with any ofthose..do it urself...

write the function call between these

```
console.time('timerName');

// Your javascript function here 

console.timeEnd('timerName');
```

This one will work only in developer tools like firebug and chrome console but very easy to deal with it.

Answer (score 0):

In Chrome

`CTRL + SHIFT + I`

Timeline tab

Hit the circle on the bottom left that says record

Mess with your site

Stop recording

Comment: He wants the Profile, not Timeline